# Execution interruption while holding a kernel spin lock

Tags: gpio, kernel, real-time

I want to toggle an GPIO pin with a certain accuracy. (i.e. latency about 1 us). I have a Raspberry Pi 3 model.

Therefore I wrote a simple test kernel module.
The toggling loop does basically this:

```
     spin_lock_irqsave(&my_lock, flags);
   while(count)
   {
       volatile int k;
       iowrite32(16, (u8*)gpio+0x1c);
       for(k=0;k< 10;k++);
       iowrite32(16, (u8*)gpio+0x28);
       for(k=0;k< 10;k++);
       count--;
   }
   spin_unlock_irqrestore(&my_lock, flags);
```

I monitor the pin with an oscilloscope and trigger for gaps.
Here I can see that every few seconds I get latency gaps up to 5us.

My question is: Where do those gaps come from?

My understanding was that the spin lock disables IRQs for the core my driver is running. And therefore I have assumed to have the whole CPU core for my driver all the time.

Update 2018/08/20: I verified that spin_lock_irqsave disables IRQ but not FIQ. Does Linux/Raspberry use FIQ interrupts?

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are using Linux you might be better off asking at the raspberrypi.org [baremetal](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=72) forum.  They are probably more aware of potential glitches.

I know of two potential glitch sources.

1. Every second or so the dynamic RAM refresh rate is recalculated.  This will add a glitch of about 5µs or so.  However according to this [issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/640) that behaviour was fixed so should no longer be a problem.
2. The GPIO are accessed off the AXI bus.  If the bus is busy for other reasons this may also cause a glitch.